# Claiming *forum non conveniens* after extended "shadow litigation"

Tags: international, civil-procedure, common-law, multiple-jurisdiction, extraterritorial-jurisdiction

Can someone claim that a particular forum is inconvenient after challenging service through a proxy (the recipient), thus essentially "shadow litigating" intensively for an extended period of time?
In other words: is there a common law rule that bars invocating *forum non conveniens* after effective participation in the litigation?
The example would be: an agent was served and contested service, but it was the principal who called the shots and paid the legal bills for the drawn out litigation on that point - effectively "shadow litigation." Would the principal then be barred from the claiming that the forum was inconvenient for litigation on the merits?

Comment: are we talking corporations being sued? Or is agent here a lawyer hired by the answering party?

Comment: Defendant in country A was sued in country B, and a business agent was served  on her behalf in country B. Service was approved, but only after extended and expensive litigation, that was (secretly) directed by the defendant. Two years later she claims that country B is forum non conveniens. Would she be estopped since she conducted litigation behind the scenes on the question of service? I seem to remember a common law principle to that effect, but it escapes me...

Comment: Please [edit] to incorporate these informations and clarify what you want. Note that Legal Advice is banned here.

Comment: The identity of Country A is probably relevant. Different jurisdictions have different rules for *forum non conveniens*.

Comment: I am specifically avoiding the identity of the countries so as to focus on the common law rule, and avoid Legal Advice. I am fascinated by the growth of the rule in different directions (especially in this day and age of the global world). The rule has the ring of equity to it, which might bar any manipulative use. But it also has a very practical side to it, balancing systemic and personal costs. These are considerations of contrasting jurisprudences. My encounter with the particular case has aroused my curiosity - but also my frustration at its elusiveness.

Comment: Country of at least party A, better even also B matters: Example: [Hughes v. Benjamin](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkdgWccrJAy5d0s7bC3UIBjiWhMVy0fgc) [es. videos 2 & 3 of the list] - Benjamin is a resident of the UK, Hughs of the US. Hughs' attorney was sent the service by mail, Hughs' tries to go for default after no response. The suit was delivered but not with a signature, no agent got the mail. The service was improper, the court ruled. [FRCP 4F](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_4) was the reason why the dismissal was ruled improper.

Comment: FRCP 4FC can make *any* service impossible if B's country bans service in the ways acceptable by the US courts.

Comment: But, unless I am wrong, there the defendant did not "shadow box" behind the scenes. If "FNC" is a question of fairness - that would be bad faith; if economic convenience alone - that would be the only consideration. (Service was validated; it is the extended litigation on the issue of service that might preclude the claim of "non-conveniens.")